# Improve Darkness/Lightness algorithm Javascript hex Color

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I need some help to find why this Darkness/Lightness algorithm Javascript hex Color it's failing in some cases, please run the snippet, I would like to understand why its failing more than have an solution, because I will use a new algorthim with hls color + %.

```js
function similarColor(hex, percent) {
   console.log(hex);
  
   var a = parseInt(hex.substring(1,3),16);
   var b = parseInt(hex.substring(3,5),16);
   var c = parseInt(hex.substring(5,6),16);
    
   a = parseInt(a * (100 + percent) / 100);
   b = parseInt(b * (100 + percent) / 100);
   c = parseInt(c * (100 + percent) / 100);    
         
   a = (a<255)?a:255;  
   b = (b<255)?b:255;  
   c = (c<255)?c:255;  
  
   var aa = (a.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+a.toString(16):a.toString(16);
   var bb = (b.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+b.toString(16):b.toString(16);
   var cc = (c.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+c.toString(16):c.toString(16);
    
   return "#"+aa+bb+cc;
}

//Error
document.getElementById('errorColor').style.backgroundColor=similarColor('#074E7C', 50);


//Well working
  document.getElementById('newColor2').style.backgroundColor=similarColor('#2A7C2A', 50);
document.getElementById('newColor3').style.backgroundColor=similarColor('#FC1479', 50); 
document.getElementById('newColor4').style.backgroundColor=similarColor('#FCFC6F', 50);
```

```html
Error<br>
<div style="background-color:#074E7C">#074E7C</div>
<div id="errorColor">lightness</div>
<hr> 
Correct<br>
<div style="background-color:#2A7C2A">original</div>
<div id="newColor2">lightness</div>
<hr>
Looks bad<br>
<div style="background-color:#FC1479">original</div>
<div id="newColor3">lightness</div>
<hr>
Correct<br>
<div style="background-color:#FCFC6F">original</div>
<div id="newColor4">lightness</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: What is the algorithm supposed to do? what is wrong with what you have?

Comment: Could it be    var c = parseInt(hex.substring(5,7),16); ?

Comment: @b2238488 yeah, my bad, thanks< var c = parseInt(hex.substring(5,7),16);

Answer (score 0):

My bad,
In this example the error was because the code was missing last char of the hex bucket.  the var C was 7=blue but should be 7C=blackgreen.  fixed line: `var c = parseInt(hex.substring(5,7),16);`